# Same question appears two times

Tags: discussion, questions

Same question appear two times asked by the same user. Hows it's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: that user reposted their question. Presumably they deleted the original one because it got downvoted. Well, [reposting it isn't exactly helping their case either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881122/complete-procedure-to-implement-apns-server-with-php-for-ios)...

The question list is cached so the original question will remain around for a bit, but if you try to click it now you'll see that the question is deleted.