# Same question displayed more than once

Tags: bug

I got the following while looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/openerp

[image: Duplicate results]

Basically some questions appear more than once (Both links lead to the same place (question, answers, rep, etc seem to be the same).

Example questions (the ones from the screen shot):

- [How to execute custom function when data loaded in Odoo 8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051522/how-to-execute-custom-function-when-data-loaded-in-odoo-8-x)
- [POS - Add a new product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623648/pos-add-a-new-product)
- [Odoo / openerp:- subdomain based db_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535433/odoo-openerp-subdomain-based-db-filter)

Scrolling down revealed more such questions, let me know if more examples are needed.

This was observed while logged in, using Firefox 50.1.0 on Fedora 24 (64 bit). Tried the same with a different browser: Chromium  55.0.2883.87, not logged in - same behavior, same questions get duplicated.

Seems different from [Same question appears two times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321843/same-question-appears-two-times)

*Edit:*

I think this happens to links that have both `openerp` and `odoo` tags.

This question is interesting, because it contains two sets of synonyms:
openerp:odoo and openerp-8:odoo-8:

[How to execute custom function when data loaded in Odoo 8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051522/how-to-execute-custom-function-when-data-loaded-in-odoo-8-x)

It appears twice under https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/openerp, but only once under https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/openerp-8

*Edit 2:*

Managed to observe the same on my Android phone, using Chrome (not logged in):

[image: duplicate results mobile]

Also when I click one of the links, both change color as visited.

Comment: Can't reproduce this myself, there are probably more factors involved. Do you have any of these tags in your favorite tags?

Comment: 0doo-8, but I guess favororite tags are not a factor, as I see these even when not logged in. I just managed to reproduce it on my phone using chrome browser. Will edit my answer in a bit to add a screenshot

Comment: I can confirm. I also see double questions in the link proveded

Comment: I could have sworn that tag was "openderp" for a second...

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure if it is a cache issue, as I still see duplicated entries.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior with the CSS tag in Unanswered Questions under [No Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/css?tab=noanswers). [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGK2S.png). The duplicate listing continues to persist after several minutes, despite refreshing.